# Swfit, AVFoundation startRecording when isRecording is true

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I want to record a long video, divide it into several parts for some seconds in different paths during the recording process (like instagram stories).

I try stopRecording and startRecording again, but I have error or lost part video (between stopRecording and startRecording again) Developer documentation says

> You can call this method when they want to stop recording new samples
>   to the current file, and do not want to continue recording to another
>   file. If you want to switch from one file to another, you should not
>   call this method. Instead you should simply call
>   startRecording(to:recordingDelegate:) with the new file URL.

But, when I called startRecording() second time (isRecording == true) delegate called

```
func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {}
```

and error is

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11859 "Movie recording
>   cannot be started" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Movie recording
>   cannot be started, NSUnderlyingError=0x281efcc00 {Error
>   Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-16419 "(null)"},
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Stop the movie recording in progress and
>   try again., NSLocalizedFailureReason=A movie recording is already in
>   progress.}

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem like this

I made a flag

```
var isRecordong: Bool = false
```

in my start action, after start recording, I change flag to true and start timer

```
@IBAction func startRecording() {

    movieOutput.startRecording(to: outputURL, recordingDelegate: self)
    isRecording = true

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: duration, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] ( _ ) in

            guard let weakSelf = self else { return }

            if weakSelf.movieOutput.isRecording == true {
                weakSelf.movieOutput.stopRecording()
            }
        })
}
```

next I implement delegate method didFinishRecordingTo for make loop recording

```
func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {

    if self.isRecording {
        movieOutput.startRecording(to: newOutputURL, recordingDelegate: self)
    } else {
        //perform action after recording
    }

}
```

in my stop action I stop recording, change flag to false and remove timer

```
@IBAction func stopRecording() {
    isRecording = false
    if movieOutput.isRecording == true {
        movieOutput.stopRecording()
    } else {
        //perform action after recording, if action and timer will work simultaneously
    }
    timer.invalidate()
}
```

Some important points

- There is a slight delay between starting and stopping recording (that is, this interval is not recorded), but it is about 0.1 seconds, this suits me.
- The first file is 0.1–0.3 seconds smaller than the rest and duration of file, this is due to the timer. Also the duration of each file will differ from the timer by several tenths of a second